# Throw Exception in Angular 6 HttpInterceptor

Tags: angular6

I am using `HttpInterceptor > intercept` to validate user authentication. When authentication expired, exception should be thrown to stop further request.

The error is not cached and repeated query for the same 'url' is received. Is there a simple way to throw an error from `intercept` and stop further request in Angular 6?

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  if (this.authExpiry <= Date.now()) {
    console.log('Authentication expired!');
    throw new Error("401");
    // or
    // return throwError("401");
  }
  return this.sendRequest(request, next);
}
```

Comment: I think throw doesnot stop the execution and adding return in else block may solve ur issue or else add a return in if block to stop execution

Comment: @GvsAkhil, Throw with return too is not helping. I have modified the question to reflect the same.

Comment: consider that it is better practice to let request go to the server with Token which is either expired or not. Once you got the 401 then we need to stop the execution of the App requests...

Comment: @ganesh045 When you know that the token is expired and will fail, why to allow the request? My intention is to block the expired authentication request, so that intentional login with wrong credentials are noted.